# Debezium should only read new changes

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

Even though I'm using snapshot.mode:schema_only, I'm getting complete records of the database whereas I only want the new ones. Are there any other modifications that I should do?

This is the config of my source connector:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
 localhost:8083/connectors/ \
 -d '{    "name": "inventory-connector", 
          "config": { "connector.class":"io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
                      "tasks.max": "1",
                      "snapshot.mode":"schema_only",
                      "database.hostname": "----", 
                      "database.port": "3306",
                      "database.user": "---",
                      "database.password": "----",
                      "database.server.id": "1",
                      "database.server.name": "data", 
                      "database.whitelist": "---",
                      "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092", 
                      "database.history.kafka.topic": "dbhistory.---"              
                    } 
      }'
```

Comment: Which version of Debezium are you using? Can you edit your question to include the full config?

Comment: I've added the config, and the version I'm using is 1.3.